# Formatting hour in java 20h 10m 5000s to 20h 10m 10s

Tags: java, date, date-formatting, hour

I am trying to create a small program that we give a wrong time for example: 20h 10m 5000s and that transforms it giving me back 20h 10m 50s. But I am unable to show you the code to see if you can help me, thank you very much :)

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class EejercicioBasico3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Date date = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat dateForm = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
 
        String UserDate = dateForm.format(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Escriba una hora en formato hh-mm-ss"));
        
        System.out.println(date);
        System.out.println(UserDate);
    
    }
}
```

Comment: How does your input look like `20:10:5000` or `20h 10m 5000s` ?

Comment: My input look like in this format 20h 10m 5000s.

Comment: The code that you included in the question has nothing to do with your question, then. Please remove it. And if you can't include the wrong code that you are having trouble with, I don't think we can help you. First, because we don't have the information we need. And second, because Stack Overflow is a place where you ask questions that may be useful to other programmers, and without the code, the question is not useful.

Comment: Yes, we need to see the code you've written. And a definition of your algorithm for transforming dates. What does `20h 10m 5001s` map to?

Comment: Perhaps it is a matter of the language that they do not understand me. But I just try to ask the user for a "data or date" that will enter something like this -> 20H 10M 500s in a JOptionPane, and I need to transform it into this -> 20h 10m 50s by printing it by console.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Also a `Date` is a point in time, not an amount of time. Instead you need `Duration` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Do you want 5000s to become 10s or 50s? And what about other amounts of seconds, is there a rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Removing excess digits

I tend to understand from your question and comments that you are assuming that the user may type too many digits by mistake. I am further assuming that each number may be in the interval from 0 or 00 to 59, and any digits that make the number greater than 59 or wider than two digits are to be removed. It’s probably not perfect, but may get you started.

```
    String inputTimeString = "20h 10m 5000s";
    String outputTimeString
            = inputTimeString.replaceAll("([6-9]|[0-5]\\d)\\d+", "$1");
    System.out.println(outputTimeString);
```

Output is:

> 20h 10m 50s

The regular expression first matches either a digit in the range 6 – 9 or two digits starting with 0 through 5 to ensure that we got at most 59. This or these digits are captured as a group using round brackets around the group in the regexp. After the group any number of excess digits is matched. In the replacement string I use `$1` to denote that the digits should be replaced with just what was matched in capturing group no. 1 (the only capturing group in this case).

Try another example:

```
    String inputTimeString = "60h 010m 777s";
```

> 6h 01m 7s

**Reservation:** If this is a basic exercise from school, your teacher may have another solution in mind, but you can judge that better. If you haven’t learnt regular expressions, you probably should not hand in a solution that uses them. Maybe you were expected to iterate through the input string and add characters that are OK to a string buffer where you collect your output.

### Converting excess seconds to minutes and hours

If instead you want excess seconds — over 59 seconds — converted to minutes and hours, use the `Duration` class:

```
    String isoTimeString = "PT" + inputTimeString.replaceAll(" ", "");
    Duration dur = Duration.parse(isoTimeString);
    String outputTimeString = String.format("%dh %dm %ds",
            dur.toHours(), dur.toMinutesPart(), dur.toSecondsPart());
    
    System.out.println(outputTimeString);
```

> 21h 33m 20s

`Duration.parse()` requires ISO 8601 format. This is obtained from your format by prefixing `PT` (think *period of time*) and removing the spaces. The `String.format()` call reproduces your format.

### Always avoid Date and SimpleDateFormat

The classes you were trying to use, `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`, are poorly designed and long outdated and were never meant for a job like this. I recommmend that you never use them and always use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your time work. The `Duration` class is part of java.time.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the bottom line would be...just don't accept an entry of: `20h 10m 5000s`. Although the data is supplied through an **Input Dialog** window it can still be validated to contain the desired format (*which is **clearly** shown as an example within the dialog*) and if it isn't, inform the User to enter it again. Your code really shouldn't need to accommodate every typo and automatically correct it. It should however determine that there is a typo and inform the User to correct it or discard the input data altogether. Your application sets the rules, not the User (unfortunately however this may not be the case for everything). This may seem blunt but, you can't make everything idiot proof because tomorrow, there will just be a better idiot. Make the idiot do it right.

**Determine your application's Time Entry rules:**

- Time is to be in **three** specific units: *Hours*, *Minutes*, and
  *Seconds*.
- Time is in **24 hour format** meaning there is no such thing as AM or PM.
- Each time unit (Hour, Minute, or Second) is to be comprised of **two** integer digits (ex: 15-32-05).
- A separator character **must** be applied to separate each time
  unit. The allowable character in this case is the Hyphen (**-**) or Minus character.

---

```
String userTime = "";
while (userTime.isEmpty()) {
    userTime = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "<html>Enter a time in "
                + "<font color=red><b>hh-mm-ss</b></font> format:<br><br></html>");
    if (userTime == null) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Time entry Canceled!", "Entry Canceled",
                JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        return;
    }
    if (!userTime.matches(
               "^([0-1][0-9][-]|[2][0-3][-])([0-5][0-9][-])([0-5][0-9])$")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Time format supplied!", 
                                "Invalid Entry", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        userTime = "";
    }
}

String[] timeUnits = userTime.split("-");
String time = new StringBuilder("").append(timeUnits[0]).append("h ")
                 .append(timeUnits[1]).append("m ").append(timeUnits[2])
                 .append("s").toString();
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "<html>User supplied the time of:<br><br>"
        + "<center><font color=blue><b>" + time + "</b></font></center></html>",
        "Invalid Entry", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

Obviously you don't need to do this sort of thing in a loop but you get the idea I'm sure.